# SLSQP does not drive array as a design variable

Tags: openmdao

I am a newbie in openmdao. Recently I am trying to implement a dummy wing optimization problem to learn openmdao. I have come up with a weird problem that I wanted to ask about. I am using a bspline to define twist and t/c distribution. The optimization setup is working when I use COBYLA, DifferentialEvolution or DOEdriver as the driver. But when I set SciPy SLSQP, the control points for these splines does not change during iterations. What could be the problem?

Below is the main section where I define the problem...

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    driver = om.ScipyOptimizeDriver() ;   
    driver.options['optimizer']='SLSQP' 
    
    driver = om.DOEDriver(om.LatinHypercubeGenerator(samples=10))
       
    
    recorder_name ='cases'
    recorder = om.SqliteRecorder(recorder_name+'.sql')
    
    driver = om.DifferentialEvolutionDriver()
    driver.options['max_gen']=10
    
     
    
    min_step = 0.01
    n_cp = 4
    n_vsp_segment = 4
    
    ivc = om.IndepVarComp()
    ivc.add_output('Mach',0.2)
    ivc.add_output('b',7.)
    ivc.add_output('cr',3.)
    ivc.add_output('taper',0.5)
    ivc.add_output('twist_cp',np.ones(n_cp))
    ivc.add_output('tc_cp',np.ones(n_cp)*0.1)
    
    Scomp = om.SplineComp(method='bsplines',x_interp_val = np.linspace(0.,1.,int(n_vsp_segment)),
                          num_cp = n_cp, interp_options={"order": min(n_cp, 4)})
    Scomp.add_spline(y_cp_name='twist',y_interp_name='twist_vsp')
    Scomp.add_spline(y_cp_name='tc',y_interp_name='tc_vsp')
       
    
    model = om.Group()
    model.add_subsystem('IVC',ivc)
    model.add_subsystem('spline',Scomp)    
    model.add_subsystem('VSP',VSP(n_vsp_segment=n_vsp_segment))  
    model.add_subsystem('AVL',AVL())    
    model.add_subsystem('obj',om.ExecComp('obj = (CD0+CDi)*100+0.1/tr'))
    model.add_subsystem('cons',om.ExecComp('c1 = Sref-40.'))
    
    model.connect('IVC.twist_cp','spline.twist')
    model.connect('spline.twist_vsp','VSP.twist')
    
    model.connect('IVC.tc_cp','spline.tc')
    model.connect('spline.tc_vsp','VSP.tc')
    
    model.connect('IVC.Mach',['VSP.Mach','AVL.Mach'])
    model.connect('IVC.b',['VSP.b','AVL.b'])
    model.connect('IVC.cr','VSP.cr')
    model.connect('IVC.taper','VSP.taper')
    
    model.connect('VSP.CD0','obj.CD0')
    model.connect('VSP.Sref',['AVL.Sref','cons.Sref'])
    model.connect('VSP.Cref','AVL.Cref')
    model.connect('VSP.MOMref','AVL.MOMref')
    model.connect('VSP.tr','obj.tr')
    
    model.connect('AVL.CDi','obj.CDi') 
    
    
    prob = om.Problem(model,driver)
    prob.model.add_design_var('IVC.tc_cp',lower=0.05,upper=0.1,indices=[1,2,3])
    prob.model.add_design_var('IVC.twist_cp',lower=-10.,upper=2.,indices=[1,2,3])
    prob.model.add_design_var('IVC.cr',lower=2,upper=6)
    prob.model.add_design_var('IVC.b',lower=10,upper=20)
    prob.model.add_design_var('IVC.taper',lower=0.2,upper=0.9) 
    prob.model.add_constraint('cons.c1',upper=0)
    prob.model.add_objective('obj.obj',scaler=100)
    
    prob.setup(check=True)
      
    prob.set_val('IVC.cr',4.)
    prob.set_val('IVC.b',10.)
    prob.set_val('IVC.taper',0.8)
    
    prob.driver.options['debug_print'] = ['desvars','ln_cons','nl_cons','objs']
    
    prob.run_driver()
```

Comment: My first inclination is that SLSQP is not changing them because it thinks they have no impact on the objective and constraints, because the gradients of those quantities wrt those design variables is zero.  Other drivers you listed are not gradient-based optimizers.

Have you run `prob.run_model(); prob.check_partials(compact_print=True)` to see if there are any incorrect partials in your model?  If that reports correct derivatives, then there may be an issue with the total derivatives which we can tackle, but this is typically a partials issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem seems to be working with gradient free methods, but not with gradient based one. Hence it's a safe bet that there is a problem with the derivatives.

I'm going to assume that since you're using VSP and AVL, that you're doing finite differences. You likely need to set up different FD settings to get decent derivative approximations. You probably want to use the `[appox_totals][1]` method at the top level of your problem.

You will likely need to experiment with larger FD steps sizes and absolute vs relative steps. You can get a visualization of what your intial jacobian looks like using the [OpenMDAO scaling report.](http://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/3.16.0/other_useful_docs/om_command.html#openmdao-scaling) Your problem doesn't look badly scaled at first glance, but the jacobian visualization in that report might be helpful to you as you test FD step sizes.

Comment: So both thank you to Rob and Justin. My problem was a partial derivative problem, as documented by 'check_partials'. I was assigning derivatives manually in 'setup_partials' and apparently I forgot to define twist related ones. That solved my problem. I've already done a trade-off study for step_type and step sizes for FD within 'setup_partials'. As I understood, if I use 'approx_totals' command, then I don't need to write 'setup_partials' command. Is that correct?

Comment: I have another question related to my problem setup. I have created 2 explicit components for VSP and AVL. Twist variable is an input to VSP which then creates a .vsp3 file. Physically AVL comp does not get twist as a geometrical input but that comp parses .vsp3 file and creates its own .avl geom file. So in this setting, I have realized that AVL output CDi have zero-valued derivative with twist variable, therefore this is not a healty setup. If  I put all the external code to a single component, derivatives are fine naturally.. But how can I keep having 2 individual comps for AVL and VSP ?

Comment: I can't quite follow what you're asking. But this sounds like its a separate question related to how to handle file based data transfer. I would recommend you ask a new question for a better answer. Briefly, I would recommend you pass only floating point data between components (not file pointers). You can handle all the I/O writing inside the compute methods. This is the only good approach to getting derivatives in OpenMDAO